# ROS Noetic installation issues!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i tried to install ROS on my Raspberry pi 3 and have problems with setting up the key. I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 on my Raspberry pi.
i control it via ssh connection from my laptop.

and try to install ros by following the roswiki instructions.

i can't get very far because i can't set up the key in step 1.3 correctly.

I am using the following line:
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -

and get this output:
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

I am not very familiar with these stuff. Do I need to pre-install something for this to work? or is the key on the roswiki homepage not up to date?

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382815/ros-noetic-installation-issues!/) by [Musab.c](https://answers.ros.org/users/78191/musab.c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-20**:
Please double-check:

1. is `curl` installed on the server? If I'm not mistaken, it does not come preinstalled on (at least) the server version of 20.04. You should receive a `Command not found` error a few lines above the error you show)
2. If it is installed, are you behind a proxy? Does just the first part (i.e. only the `curl -s http...`) command print a key to the command line? If not, what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem,
it turned out that the ip address of my Raspberry pi was the truble maker. i have created a static ip for my ssh connection. Now every thing is working.
But thanks for your reply.

---

Originally posted by [Musab.c](https://answers.ros.org/users/78191/musab.c/) with karma: 16 on 2021-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0